# Can't receive data from io.emit()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to send data to all clients just to test how socket.io works.
I can't seem to get any data back from the server, no matter how I try.

The event is fired, so the data gets to the server side, but it doesn't arrive to the clients.

On the server side, I do this:

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chatMessage', data => {
        console.log(data);
        io.emit(data);
    });
});
```

The console.log() here works, so its fine until that line.

On the client side I tried to simplify things to see the result like this:

```js
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('chatMessage', {a:"fsdfsdfsd"});
});

socket.on('chatMessage', data =>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

The socket.emit() fires, but it doesn't arrive anywhere.
I have never used socket.io before, but I read the docs and it said io.emit() sends the data to all connected clients.

Just in case, I tried with multiple clients connected, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: instead of `io.emit(data)`, use `io.emit('chatMesage', data)`? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would recommend is to check if the client is really connecting to the server socket by adding a `console.log()` inside your on connection block in the server side.

Also, your `io.emit(data);` in the server side won't work since the first parameter of the emit function should be the event name.